# Error: expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
booking.save(function (error, data) {
    error ? console.log(error) : res.redirect('/');
});
```

This code is causing the following error to be displayed in Sublime Text:

```
Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression
```

Why is that? What is wrong with my code? It's working 100%. I don't see the error.

Answer (score 4):

It is [JSLint error](https://jslinterrors.com/expected-an-assignment-or-function-call) not JS error.

In your case it considers that ternary operators should been used only for assignment such as

```
var foo = bar ? 2 : 3;
```

since there is no assignmet JSLint consider that string useless. Change it to `if-else` block or use JSHint with proper settings instead.

Comment: I know.. but, why and how fix that?

Comment: do you agree with JSLint?

Comment: @SuchMuchFunny JSLint is very opinionated and many people will disagree with some of its recommendations. If you're one of those people, you might prefer a more customizable tool such as [JSHint](http://jshint.com/).

Comment: Yes. The expression is little bit weird. In this case if-else should be better. But I usually do not agree with JSLint since it make your code only Crockford will like. =)

Comment: @RolandBertolom Many of Crockford's code convention rules will appear in a new light, if you'd write your code using a simple text editor, i.e. without syntax highlighting.

Comment: @Teemu nice point of view! Never tried it. Maybe you right. But really if you are advanced enough to use code linter why do you still use simple text editor?

Comment: @RolandBertolom Maybe those rules are just that old? Say 10 - 15 years ago, editors with JS syntax highlighting were quite rare.

Comment: @Teemu, so for those days that was appropriate tool. But now it should be admitted as little bit dated.

Answer (score 0):

It expects the body of a function to be a list of statements. JSLint throws this warning because

```
error ? console.log(error) : res.redirect('/');
```

is an expession, not a statement. To make the warning go away, use an `if...else` statement instead.

```
if(err) console.log(error);
else res.redirect('/');
```

Comment: but i prefer use the one line statement, is more clear and beautifies the code.. can i use?

Comment: @SuchMuchFunny Sure you can use it, it will work fine, but some linting tools will cough up on it since an expression instead of a statement is often a mistake.